# CakePHP 3.0 cake Console error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm starting a new project with cakePHP 3.0 and I'm having problems with the cake console.
When I try to run any command like:

> bin/cake bake

I get the following error message:

X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

**Warning**:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in **/homepages/37/d542973365/htdocs/gestioPPF/bin/cake.php** on line **33**

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in **/homepages/37/d542973365/htdocs/gestioPPF/bin/cake.php** on line **33**

I was working with the console without problems with cakePHP 2.x. Anyone know if I missed some previous configuration?

Thanks in advance,
Cadí.

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have. Type php --version in the console, what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> X-Powered-By: **PHP/4.4.9** Content-type: text/html

**If** this is the php version (4.4) you're running you won't be able to run CakePHP 3.x at all. Update your php version and see if it works then.

One of the first things to do when using something new is to check it's [requirements and documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html). It cleary states there that you need at least *PHP 5.4.16 or greater* and a few other things.

Comment: I see. I have enabled php 5.5 for this domain, so I assumed that this is the versión I'm using. I've read that I need to change bin/cake to force the console to use the version changing php -> php5.5.

Answer (score 0):

cakePHP 3.0 : try this update the file bin/cake => **php** to **php5.5**

```
exec php "$CONSOLE"/cake.php "$@"
```

to

```
exec php5.5 "$CONSOLE"/cake.php "$@"
```